# JUnit uses wrong Base64

Tags: eclipse, junit, websphere, base64

I wanna use the class Base64 from commons-codec 1.5 and when I run the code on Server this works fine. My application runs on Websphere 7.0.

But when I run my JUnit tests the wrong Base64 Class is choosen, when i ask the Class with:

```
System.out.println(Base64.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

the output is: file:/C:/EProg/IBM/SDP80/runtimes/base_v7/plugins/com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar

Thats definitly the wrong Version.

And an error occurs because of the wrong Version:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)

The crazy thing is, that happens only it i choose one Test and run it with Run As: JUnit Test in Eclipse, if I run the whole thing with Maven everthing works fine.

I use JUnit 4.8.1 and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 with some Plugins for Websphere, GWT and Maven.``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar` is an OSGi bundle, and in WebSphere (which is built on an OSGi container), the classes in `org.apache.commons.codec.binary` are not visible to applications because that package is not exported by the OSGi bundle (you can examine the list of exported packages by looking at the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file in `com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar`). That explains why you don't encounter any issue when running your application in WebSphere.

On the other hand, when you add that JAR to a Java project in Eclipse, it will be treated like a simple JAR, not an OSGi bundle, and all packages will be visible. In your case this creates a conflict with another `commons-codec` dependency.

I guess that the reason why you don't encounter that issue in Maven is that `com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar` is only a dependency of your Eclipse project, but not of your Maven project.

Unfortunately there are not many (simple) ways to solve that issue. One is to remove `com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar` from your Java project (I doubt that you are actually using Apache SOAP). The other is to change the order, so that your other `commons-codec` dependency comes before `com.ibm.ws.prereq.soap.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a class path issue. More precisely, Eclipse integration with Maven. I would investigate Eclipse dependencies and make sure that it uses Maven for dependency management. 
You can do it in two ways, either you can run mvn eclipse:eclipse command or use M2Eclipse plugin. If you use the later, then there is a update dependency option, in the project context menu.

Comment: I use M2E and in the Maven Dependency Folder/Container everthing seems to be allright. And wenn I run the JUnit tests with Maven it works. But when I run them with Eclipse/JUnit it uses the wrong Base64 class. I have not found a place to configure JUnit in Eclipse to use only the maven dependencies. The reason I want run it with Eclipse/JUnit is because I want to debug my tests. And debugging when using Maven to run the JUnit tests is a real bad solution.

Comment: I figured out how to get the JUnit tests running, buts not a real solution, it only helps that I can debug the test: Rightclick to the maven modul where the test belong --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Remove WebSphere Application Server v7.0. Now I can debug my test, but after I had to add the Server again. So for me this can not be the ideal way to handle this.

Comment: I still believe that this problem is because of Maven integration with eclipse. Eclipse is not my primary IDE, so I might be wrong, but can you try  Right Click -> Under "Maven" option -> Enable Dependency Management. Also if you have added server dependency in POM, can you also change scope to "Provided"